# How to fill color exactly like this image color?

Tags: iphone, ios, uicolor

Please see this image:

[image]

I need to fill the same color with same effect in a bar. I tried to use

```
[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bar.png"]];
```

But didn't get success. It created the same effect but with patterns.

Comment: Sorry bro i have no time to code exact answer but you can have a look at [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5) and [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2033/core-graphics-101-lines-rectangles-and-gradients). The answer is there i'm sure

Answer (score 2):

Use a 1 pixel wide image, not the 100 pixel wide one that you have. The 20th and 21st vertical columns in your image are different from the rest, hence the pattern. Check out the zoomed in version below.

[image]

Comment: Should I use your image instead?

Comment: No! Take YOUR image and edit it. Make it 1 pixel wide, not 100 pixels wide. Mine, uhhh, has window stuff and letters in it. You don't want that...

Comment: I made my image 1*1. Still getting pattern.

Comment: take a screenshot of the pattern, post it in your answer.